# How to execute openssl command at shutdown and reboot?

Tags: bash, systemd, shutdown, autorun, power-off

I want to encrypt a file and log the time at shutdown or reboot.
Here is what i do.
1.edit a bash script file to execute at shutdown or reboot.

```
vim log.sh
key="123456"
openssl enc -des3 -a -salt -in $HOME/test -k ${key} -out $HOME/test.asc
date >>  /home/log.info
```

2.edit a log.service

```
sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/log.service
[Unit]
Description=Run command at shutdown
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/bin/bash /home/log.sh


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

3.systemctl enable  log.service
4.reboot

After reboot i found that there is a date info in /home/log.info ,it means `date >>  /home/log.info` executed,no `$HOME/test.asc` there,it means `openssl enc -des3 -a -salt -in $HOME/test -k ${key} -out $HOME/test.asc` not executed.
The commands can run successfully in terminal .

```
key="123456"
openssl enc -des3 -a -salt -in $HOME/test -k ${key} -out $HOME/test.asc
```

How to fix my log.service file `/etc/systemd/system/log.service` to make openssl command  executed at shutdown and reboot?

Comment: Try to check what happens, try to catch openssl output, for example
`openssl enc -des3 -a -salt -in $HOME/test -k ${key} -out $HOME/test.asc >> /home/log.info 2>&1`

Comment: For the command `openssl enc -des3 -a -salt -in $HOME/test -k ${key} -out $HOME/test.asc >> /home/log.info 2>&1` ,

Comment: 1.test was encrypted into test.asc

Comment: 2.nothing in /home/log.info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `${HOME}` doesn't expand to what you expect. When I try it on my system it expands to nothing. So `${HOME}/test` becomes `/test`. You can check this by redirecting the error output for your openssl command in `log.sh`:

```
openssl enc -des3 -a -salt -in $HOME/test -k ${key} -out $HOME/test.asc 2> /home/log.error
```

## Solution 1:

Use absolute paths in `log.sh`

## Solution 2:

Add `User=` in service section of `log.service`. In this case make sure that the user has rights to write to the different locations where you want to write. For reference see [systemd.exec](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Environment%20variables%20in%20spawned%20processes)

> $USER, $LOGNAME, $HOME, $SHELL
>
> User name (twice), home directory, and the login shell. The variables are set for the units that have User= set, which includes user systemd instances

Answer (score 0):

`Before=` is documented in `man systemd.unit`. It's not intended for this use case. Also documented there is `WantedBy=` and `RequiredBy=`. The latter sounds like what is desired here, but your logging fails, it could block shutdown. `WantedBy=` won't block shutdown if it fails. Read about them both and see which one fits your case better.

I would recommend a file structure like this:

```

```
[Unit]
Description=Run command at shutdown

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/bin/bash /home/log.sh


[Install]
WantedBy=shutdown.target reboot.target
```

```

Your `Install` block was setting the service to start at boot time, which is not what you want. The new syntax will set the service to be active at shutdown time when you use `systemctl enable log.service` to enable it.

I have not tested this method of run-at-shutdown with systemd. Let us know how it works!